# my ssh sessions are randomly killed on Debian

Tags: ssh, debian, troubleshooting

I have a Debian 6.0.1 vanilla install, and I use PUTTY to ssh into it.  I will usually have 3 or 4 PUTTY login shells running at the same time.

What I'll find is that if I leave my computer for a couple of hours, I'll find that 1 out of 4 shells will be terminated.  If it were a network issue, I would expect all 4 sessions to be down, but it's always just 1 or sometimes 2.  It's really strange.

Would anyone know what this phenomenon is?  Is there something in the logs I could use to figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to try is the [keepalive feature](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#S4.13.4) in PuTTY.

If this resolves your issue, it means that you likely have a network device (e.g. firewall or NAT) between the two hosts that closes connections after a period of idleness. If it doesn't resolve your issue, it means there are network problems causing dropped packets between the the two hosts.

Try it out, and if it doesn't help please update your question with more details on the network between your two hosts.

Comment: Thank you, this worked!  This is weird because on another system it doesn't drop my sessions after a certain time, but maybe it's a setting with sshd that I will need to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

maybe CTRL-Q will recover the shell: check here -> http://raamdev.com/recovering-from-ctrls-in-putty

> Apparently CTRL+S actually does XOFF, which means the terminal will accept key strokes but won’t show the output of anything. It will appear as if your terminal is dead when it’s really just waiting to be turned back on. The fix? Simply press CTRL+Q to turn flow-control on (XON). If you pressed a whole bunch of keys before pressing CTRL+Q, you’ll see the output from those keystrokes.

Cheers